# Error retrieving field value from bean:name at JasperReports

Tags: java, jasper-reports

I got the error message which i mentioned in the title. I tried everything that I found in different forums but nothing worked.

**This is my Bean Class:**

```
public class NameBean {
    private String reportName, shortDescription, description;

    public NameBean(String reportName, String shortDescription, String description) {
        this.reportName = reportName;
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getName(){
        return reportName;
    }

    public String getShortDescription() {
        return shortDescription;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setName(String reportName){
        this.reportName = reportName;
    }

    public void setShortDescription(String shortDescription) {
        this.shortDescription = shortDescription;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }
}
```

**This is the Factory class:**

```
public  class TestFactory {

    public static ArrayList generateCollection() {
        ArrayList collection = new ArrayList();

        collection.add(new NameBean("PS_TF_VSGM-A-2535_01", "Automatisches Starten der Online-Prüfung und -Aktualisierung", 
                "Der Konfigurationsparameter zur Online-Prüfung und -Aktualisierung(MODE_ONLINE_CHECK) ist auf den Wert First konfiguriert. Es wird eine eGK in das Kartenterminal des Konnektorsimulators gesteckt für die im laufenden Quartalnoch keine Online-Prüfung durchgeführt wurde."));

        collection.add(new EntranceValuesBean("eingeschaltet", "online", "Ohne TLS", "Standard (PTV 1.6.0)", "Mandat > Terminal > Karte"));

        return collection;
    }
}
```

**This is my XML**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<jasperReport xmlns="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/jasperreports http://jasperreports.sourceforge.net/xsd/jasperreport.xsd" name="test" pageWidth="595" pageHeight="842" columnWidth="535" leftMargin="20" rightMargin="20" topMargin="20" bottomMargin="20" uuid="2f6e4db4-9f8f-4ffe-9759-6e1fd142f492">
    <property name="template.type" value="columnar"/>
    <property name="com.jaspersoft.studio.data.defaultdataadapter" value="src/dataset1.xml"/>
    <style name="Title" forecolor="#000000" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="50" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="SubTitle" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="18" isBold="false"/>
    <style name="Column header" forecolor="#666666" fontName="Times New Roman" fontSize="14" isBold="true"/>
    <style name="Detail" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman"/>
    <style name="Row" mode="Transparent" fontName="Times New Roman" pdfFontName="Times-Roman">
        <conditionalStyle>
            <conditionExpression><![CDATA[$V{REPORT_COUNT}%2 == 0]]></conditionExpression>
            <style mode="Opaque" backcolor="#F0EFEF"/>
        </conditionalStyle>
    </style>
    <field name="name" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[name]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="description" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[description]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <field name="shortDescription" class="java.lang.String">
        <fieldDescription><![CDATA[shortDescription]]></fieldDescription>
    </field>
    <title>
        <band height="290" splitType="Stretch">
            <staticText>
                <reportElement style="Title" x="0" y="0" width="400" height="30" uuid="756c5f0f-cbe1-46b1-9f5a-645caa1a189e"/>
                <textElement>
                    <font size="16" isBold="false"/>
                </textElement>
                <text><![CDATA[Konnektorsimmulator Testfall Protokoll: ]]></text>
            </staticText>
            <line>
                <reportElement positionType="FixRelativeToBottom" x="-20" y="80" width="551" height="1" uuid="5e41185f-9c90-45ca-839b-e28b308c1430"/>
            </line>
        </band>
    </title>
    <detail>
        <band height="91" splitType="Stretch"/>
    </detail>
</jasperReport>
```

**And this is the error I got:**

```
 net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: name.
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.fillReport(ReportControler.java:537)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler.access$20(ReportControler.java:512)
    at com.jaspersoft.studio.editor.preview.view.control.ReportControler$5.run(ReportControler.java:393)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
Caused by: net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Error retrieving field value from bean: name.
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:134)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getFieldValue(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:99)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRBeanCollectionDataSource.getFieldValue(JRBeanCollectionDataSource.java:104)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.setOldValues(JRFillDataset.java:1373)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1274)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRFillDataset.next(JRFillDataset.java:1250)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.next(JRBaseFiller.java:1056)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRVerticalFiller.fillReport(JRVerticalFiller.java:117)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.JRBaseFiller.fill(JRBaseFiller.java:580)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.fill.BaseFillHandle$ReportFill.run(BaseFillHandle.java:123)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'name' on class 'class EntranceValuesBean'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1277)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:808)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:114)
    ... 10 more
```

I have absolutely no clue how to solve this problem.

Comment: What is `EntranceValuesBean`? How did you use this class?  You should post the code with passing datasource to the report

Answer (score 0):

From the stack trace

```
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: Unknown property 'name' on class 'class EntranceValuesBean'
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getSimpleProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:1277)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getNestedProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:808)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtilsBean.getProperty(PropertyUtilsBean.java:884)
    at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.getProperty(PropertyUtils.java:464)
    at net.sf.jasperreports.engine.data.JRAbstractBeanDataSource.getBeanProperty(JRAbstractBeanDataSource.java:114)
```

It seems that the problem is due to the class **EntranceValuesBean**.
Check if the class has a getter method with name **getName** in that class.

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the advice with the class EntranceValuesBean. I deleted it and wrote the code into the class NameBean. It is working now.